# TYPO3 10 & tx_news Version 9.0.0 Pagination (max links)

Tags: tx-news

I updateted to the latest tx_news Version 9.0. Since the ViewHelper `<n:widget.paginate>` are no longer supported as of TYPO3 11, I have changed the pagination template as recommended. 
Unfortunately, so the setting of the maximum links no longer works: `settings.list.paginate.maximumNumberOfLinks = XYZ` Is there a workaround for this?

[Screenshot of cropped pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yanE6.jpg)

Thanks and best regards
Michael

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `settings.list.paginate.maximumNumberOfLinks`, class `GeorgRinger\NumberedPagination\NumberedPagination` is required.

You can use the following extension (beta) by Georg Ringer:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/numbered_pagination